# Why am I getting an undefined index error with this query?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on creating a very simple content management system... Unfortunately I'm failing to retrieve posts from my database. My error is:

> Notice: Undefined index: title in C:\wamp\www\NightOwlSoftware\index.php

```
<?php
include 'scripts/db_connect.php';
include 'scripts/functions.php';

sec_session_start();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM blog";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo'<div class="blog"><h3 class="blog">' . $row['title'] . "</h3>";
    echo'<span class="blog"> Date: ' . $row['date'] . " Tag: " . $row['tag'] . "</span><hr>";
    echo'<p class="blog">' . $row['body'] . "</p>";
}
?>
```

Here is the working script that stores data proving that my columns are all there...

```
<?php
include 'db_connect.php';
include 'functions.php';
sec_session_start();
$title = $_POST['title'];
$body = $_POST['body'];
$tag = $_POST['tag'];
$date = date_create()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$sql = "INSERT INTO blog (date, title, body, tag)
VALUES ('$date', '$title', '$body', '$tag')";
mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
mysqli_close($mysqli);
header( 'Location: ../index.php' ) ;
?>
```

Comment: Does your `blog` table have a column `title`?

Comment: It does. I have a script to store form data into the database that works (it uses the same column headers).

Comment: comment out the echos and use print_r($row) in the while loop. What are the values that you get?

Comment: A LOT of values are in there. I have two test posts and each of them has 4 columns and it looks like all the data is there.

Array ( [0] => 2013-11-26 04:14:32 [Date] => 2013-11-26 04:14:32 [1] => test[Title] => test[2] => test[Body] => test[3] => c++ [Tag] => c++ ) Array ( [0] => 2013-11-26 04:39:31 [Date] => 2013-11-26 04:39:31 [1] => Test 2[Title] => Test 2 [2] => Test 2 Body [Body] => test 2 body [3] => [Tag] => )

Comment: Can you add a snippet of the output to your post to help us?

Comment: do a var_dump($row) inside the loop and check..!

Comment: Do your fields names start with a capital letter?

Comment: Yes! Capital Letters!

Comment: So the issue was that the column names were capitalized. I didn't realize this was the issue because when I stored the data in the database I didn't capitalize the column headers and it resolved the mistake leading me to believe it wasn't an issue! Thanks so much everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's the only error you're getting (ie. date, tag, body all work fine), then you probably mis-typed something in the database creation, and don't actually have a `title` column as a result. Or maybe the column has a different name, like `name`, `subject` or `im_so_bored_i_dont_know_what_im_typing`... (sorry, I'm bored!)

Comment: I am getting an error on every echo, none of them work but all the columns are there. Unfortunately I'm working off of this tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp so I don't exactly know where to begin to debug this. I tried echoing $row but I don't think my syntax was right...

Comment: Start by reading [this](http://w3fools.com/). Then, find a tutorial that's actually worth something.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an undefined index for `title` because there is no `title` in the array `$row`.

I would recommend you look over your DB structure for the table `blog` but I would also recommend doing some basic data checks in your `while` to ensure you render only the content that exists. Look this over:

```
<?php
include 'scripts/db_connect.php';
include 'scripts/functions.php';

sec_session_start();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM blog";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if (array_key_exists('title', $row) && !empty($row['title'])) {
      echo'<div class="blog"><h3 class="blog">' . $row['title'] . "</h3>";
    }
    if (array_key_exists('date', $row) && !empty($row['date'])) {
      echo '<span class="blog"> Date: ' . $row['date'];
    }
    if (array_key_exists('tag', $row) && !empty($row['tag'])) {
      echo " Tag: " . $row['tag'] . "</span><hr>";
    }
    if (array_key_exists('body', $row) && !empty($row['body'])) {
      echo'<p class="blog">' . $row['body'] . "</p>";
    }
}
?>
```

If this all runs & nothing renders, then your DB query is flawed, so data is not returned.  A simple way to check this before the `while` loop is to dump the array to the screen to see what is there:

```
<?php
include 'scripts/db_connect.php';
include 'scripts/functions.php';

sec_session_start();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM blog";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($row);
  echo '</pre>';

 [ rest of your code goes here]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I could, I would've added this as a comment because this is not really an answer. I agree with other, that most likely - the column name in DB does not match what you have in the code.

In any case, when I am in situations like this, you could use debugger or use print_r.

In your while loop, add the print_r statement -

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
print_r($row);
echo'<div class="blog"><h3 class="blog">' . $row['title'] . "</h3>";
echo'<span class="blog"> Date: ' . $row['date'] . " Tag: " . $row['tag'] . "</span><hr>";
echo'<p class="blog">' . $row['body'] . "</p>";
}
```